# Developing REST APIs using Java for IPad application

Tags: java, web-services, api, rest

I am currently in the process of analyzing the work of developing REST APIS for an Iphone Application using Java:

1. Firstly, Has anyone worked on development of REST APIs for iPad app or any other kind what is the kind of duration that requires to do it...and are there frequent changes in the REST APIs so that the project is a long one and my job is secure...or in general once you make APIS in 4-5 months maximum then that is THE END?
2. Are they something that a guy like me with no such experience in development of REST APIs can take up, are they in general something that only a guy with relevant experience can do?
3. If there are any good material on the internet about making them or anyway for me to get started with and go ahead with this:

I have just received the information that we need to develop 6-7 APIs for a start,,,any experienced guys about how much time it can take here is a sample workflow:

*We have to click on Google maps..and based on longitude and lattitude we have to find a list of wholesale dealers related to our domain in that point and have to fetch them in JSON/XML Object.*..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Once the APIs are there, they are there and shouldn't change too often because it could break the app. So better put a lot of thought in the API design before you release it. How long it takes depends completely on the project. I can develop a REST API in a day, it could also take months, depending on the complexity.
2. It will take longer if you are inexperienced because you will need to do a lot of reading, especially when it comes to the architecture of the APIs. Again, impossible to say because we don't know your current skill-set. But in general: sure, if you are willing to learn you can do it, I don't see anything that would prevent you.
3. Lots of.. for a good framework have a look at [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/). I also once found a good read about REST APIs in general: [Link](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api?hn)

As a conclusion, it's not necessarily only about developing the APIs, but also about the data you are trying to provide. Does that data already exist? Can you query it easily? How much logic do you still need in order to provide useful APIs? Those are the questions you should ask yourself as well.

Comment: Well I am currently working on Automation using Selenium Webdriver and Junit 4...career wise which one would you suggest would be beneficial in the long run?? I know both these sound quiet different but even I thought related to APIs development process once the APIs there wont be much work to do...so presuming moderate complexity and in context of the example I gave would you think the code would freeze in 5-6 months?

Comment: Really Anirödh, how long it will take is impossible to say! This doesn't depend on the language or tools or frameworks you use, that's almost irrelevant. It solely depends on the kind of project, the requirements and your skills of course, and this is usually carefully evaluated before an offer is made. Regarding the only question that you can get an answer for, look at my links in point 3. For more you can just google or search Amazon for good literature about API design.

Comment: Humm thanks for your comments the links you provided look quiet helpful...one last question how would you look at developing REST APIs as a development skill? does it hold good future? : )

Comment: My personal opinion: absolutely, I see REST APIs (combined with JSON) as very relevant, now and in the future. This business is fast though, and what is good today might be obsolete tomorrow.

Comment: True that I think I would like to take it up...it will only boost my working skill set!

Comment: That day when I put up this question and today...after getting the experience it finally took 6 months to develop 8 APIs which are being released to the client....:-]

Comment: Well congratulations! I bet your skill-set is a lot higher now though. ;-)

Comment: Thanks...BTW I used Jersey and Jackson!